# Dispersing results from grid onto multiple pages with MCV

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datagrid

I currently have view with a grid displaying some data ( I would prefer a table but this is what was wanted). The query that returns the data can have the possibility to return 100+ records.

I would like to be able to only display 10 records at a time, and then put the rest of the results on another page, where user can click button 2,3,4 ect.

Normally I would just do this using Data-Tables, but since this is a grid, I am not quite sure how to handle this. Below is my code. If anyone could give me an idea or point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchGenericLogs", "Tools", FormMethod.Post)){


<div class="form-inline" style="height:50px; position:relative;">
    <form class="form-inline row">

        <div class="col-md-11">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LogLevelId, new SelectList(Model.LogLevels, "pkLogLevelId", "LogLevel", Model.LogLevelId), new { @class = "form-control", data_toggle = "tooltip", title = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LogLevelId) }) 

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LogSource, new SelectList(Model.LogSourceCodes, "pkLogSourceCode", "LogSource", Model.LogSource), new { @class = "form-control", data_toggle = "tooltip", title = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LogSource) }) 

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EntityId, new { @class = "form-control", type = "number", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EntityId), data_toggle = "tooltip", title = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.EntityId) }) 

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromLogDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "DateTime", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FromLogDate), data_toggle = "tooltip", title = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FromLogDate) }) 

            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToLogDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "DateTime", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ToLogDate), data_toggle = "tooltip", title = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ToLogDate) }) 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div> 

<div class="list-group">
    <div class="row list-group-item list-group-item-heading divTableHeading">
        <div class="col-md-1"> ID </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"> Source </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"> Level </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"> Entity ID </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"> Log Date </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"> Message </div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Logs)
    {
    <div class="row list-group-item">
        <div class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogId)  </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogSource)  </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogLevel) </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EntityId)  </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LogDateTime)  </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="word-break: break-word;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message) </div>
    </div>
    }
</div>}
```

I would post the controller action as well, except this app is a bit more complex than your typical Model, View, Controller. If anyone needs more info let me know. I can update OP.

Comment: You could create a partial view of your list (your `@foreach (var item in Model.Logs)` block), then make ajax requests with the page number clicked on to your controller. Then get the data using linq like this: `.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)` where pageSize is 10. Then just return the partial view for that page with the data back to your ajax call and replace that HTML in the DOM.

Comment: Also, it looks like you have a form (`Html.BeginForm`) with-in a form (`<form>`) which is invalid. You should remove that second form.

Comment: @zgood I guess this is my only option then

Comment: Well, it's not the only option. You could render out all your data at ounce then wrap every 10 `row list-group-item` in a div with a class `.page`, then write a css style to `display: none` all `.page`, then write some javascript that willl show the `.page` corresponding to the page number clicked (index position).

Comment: There are javascript plugins like [this one](https://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/) which can handle all the front-end work for you. You just need to tap into the `onPageClick` event and either make your ajax call or show/hide your `.page`